# unable to boot iOS simulator Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

I know this is repetitive question,but i tried all ways but it is not working.
I have XCode 7 and XCode 7.2 on my machine and whenever I run the code it shows "Unable to boot iOS simulator".

I also tried to uninstall Xcode by using below command,

sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all

But I am getting error "command not found". When I run "which sudo" it shows me below path -> "/usr/bin/sudo"

Am I missing anything?

Comment: xcode don't use /Developer for a while.

Comment: so if want to uninstall dev tools/Xcode how i can do that?

Comment: Before deleting xcode and download a fresh version, you can try to clean all the caches :  `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist`, `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist`, 
`~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode`, `~/Library/Application Support/Xcode`. You can also try to remove all installed simulators...

Comment: I tried this and installed Xcode again...but still I am getting same error "Unable to boot simulator"

Comment: Are you able to launch simulator by hand ? (Use spotlight to search "simulator" and launch it)

Comment: No its not getting launched

Comment: Did the app launched ? I mean do you have the title bar of the ios simulator app ? If yes then try to reset settings in the main menu. It looks like the ios simulator is launched but refused to start a simulator.

Comment: http://mandarapte.com/apple/fix-xcode-error-unable-boot-ios-simulator/

Comment: I already gone through above link its not working...I am not getting any title bar

Comment: After the install, try restarting the Mac. Xcode 6.3 onwards, there is bug which doesn't allow you to boot simulators sometimes. You have to restart it, so that all files are linked internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a lot but didn't succeed. Meanwhile I upgraded my Mac OS version to EI Captain and It worked. I know this is not answer to my question but this one solved my problem.