# Unable to boot simulator xcode 7.3

Tags: swift, xcode

I am not able to boot the simulator, this is what I got:

[image]

I tried many ways to solve it:

- Uninstalled and reinstalled Xcode 7.3 from dmg.
- Uninstalled Xcode 7.3 and reinstalled Xcode 7.0 from dmg.
- Removed simulators and added again.

But nothing is working in my case, totally frustrated. Can anyone please advice in this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have 2 xcode on your Mac?

Comment: You might want to check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32052037/unable-to-boot-the-ios-simulator-ios-7-1) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35001538/unable-to-boot-ios-simulator-xcode-7) answers, hope they are useful for your case.

Comment: I am having dmg for both xcode 7 and 7.3, only xcode 7.3 is installed in the mac. @Sohil R. Memon

Comment: OS EI Capitan is the OS installed in my system [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35001538/unable-to-boot-ios-simulator-xcode-7). @Ahmad F

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and got it working by this 3 simple steps :-

1-restart your mac and when the mac is about to start keep holding (Command + R)

2-open terminal from utilities and type this command "csrutil disable" and then restart

3- open the simulator now and check if its working if so do the same steps u did in 1,2 but use this command instead "csrutil enable"

Comment: @AustinMichael glad i can help